# Computing force using zero initial velocity and terminal velocity

Tags: forces

I am trying to compute force in newtons (and display on an LCD connected to an Arduino) and want your input about the following computations  / assumptions I am making.

Points A & B are 1 meter apart. A projectile weighing 15 grams  is launched from point A. I am assuming that initial velocity at point A is zero.  I start a timer (starts at zero) when launching the projectile. The projectile reaches point B in 450 milliseconds. Computed terminal velocity at point B is 2.22 meters per second. Then I use the following to compute force:

- F= m*a
- F = m*((terminal velocity-initial velocity)/time)
- F = (.015kg) * (2.22 mtrs per sec  – 0)/ 1 second
- F = .015kg * 2.22 mtrs per sec
- F = .0333 Newtons

Are my computations and assumptions correct ?

Comment: Are you assuming constant thrust during the flight?

Comment: Continuing the question above, if not, then your computation makes no sense. So, if this "projectile" is not continuously accelerated between A and B, then the force you calculated above has nothing to do with reality.

Comment: There  is just the initial thrust/push so I guess it is not constant and may be going down.

Comment: So in a case like this how do we compute the force applied at the point of initial thrust/ launch ? The projectile is passive( not a rocket) and has no way to maintain acceleration.

Comment: Why do you call it "computed terminal velocity"? It looks like the average velocity for something that traveled in a straight line. What else can you tell us about the projectile. Is it flying in an arc?

Comment: @webm The answer is simple: There is no way to compute the force you're after, since you have no information pertaining to it.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses which I accept !  @Floris - Maybe I used incorrect terminology - the projectile or 'object' is traveling  horizontally in a straight line on rails. Velocity at point B is just based how how much distance was covered in the given time. The object keeps going beyond point B...

Comment: OK - then it's really not a "projectile", and my answer below would have to be modified. Simplified, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an initial push followed by "free flight", then you cannot really compute the force - only the impulse (which is the integral of force and time).

After some comments back-and-forth, I think the situation is as follows:

1. Projectile is traveling in a straight line (on rails), reaching distance $D$ in time $t$
2. All impulse happens at the start of the trajectory ($\Delta t \ll t$)
3. No friction

In that case, the impulse is simply the change in momentum:

$$J = m\Delta v = m\frac{D}{t} = F \Delta t$$

It follows that

$$F = \frac{m}{t\Delta t}$$

But unless you know $\Delta t$, that's as far as you can go.

$$*-*-*$$

---

If the assumption of "flat rail" is not true (that was not clear from your question, initially) then the assumptions one has to make, and the calculations that follow, change. For others with a similar problem I will leave the original calculation here:

Assumptions:

1. Projectile is "launched" at an unknown angle, but we know the distance and the time: from this we can derive the angle
2. All the impulse is produced at the launch
3. There is no drag on the projectile during flight

If that is the case, then we can do a few calculations (none of which get you the "force" you are asking for - that's simply not possible to compute):

A projectile launched at velocity $v$ and angle $\theta$ will be in the air for a time 
$$\begin{align}t &= \frac{2 v_y}{g} \\
&= \frac{2 v \sin\theta}{g}\end{align}$$ 
and in that time it will cover a distance

$$d = v_x t = v\cos\theta ~t = \frac{v^2 \sin 2\theta}{g}$$

Since you have both the time and the distance, we can calculate the launch angle and the initial velocity:

$$2 v \sin\theta = g t\\
2 v^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta = g d$$

So

$$v\cos\theta = \frac{d}{t}\tag1\\
v\sin\theta= \frac{gt}{2}\\
\Rightarrow\\
\tan\theta = \frac{gt^2}{2d}\\
\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{gt^2}{2d}\right)$$

Once you have the angle, the launch velocity can be found from (1); and from this, the impulse

$$J = m\Delta v = F\Delta t$$

Unless you make an assumption about the duration $\Delta t$ of the impulse, you cannot get from that value to a force; however, if you know the launch mechanism (perhaps it's a spring that acts over a short distance) you may be able to get a force. If you give more details, I might be able to improve on this answer.